# Stripe payout clarification

Tags: php, stripe-payments

Hello my logic is explained here

Let's say i'm a marketplace for example, i allow John to sell lamps online. Then, Alice comes and wants to buy a lamp from John on his website. i use the code mentioned below to charge Alice and send the funds to John's account directly.

i got stripe error "Add a bank account or debit card to enable payouts."

for payouts, John(shop owner) needs bank account?
i have John(shop owner) stripe checkout card details (token, cardid), its not enough ?

Comment: You need to use [Stripe Connect](https://stripe.com/docs/connect) and have "John" as a connected account.

Comment: i used stripe connect and connected john account , payouts are restricted it says "Add a bank account or debit card to enable payouts."  John(shop owner) needs bank account? i have John(shop owner) stripe checkout card details (token, cardid), its not enough ?

Comment: Correct, it's not enough. You can't pay out to a PaymentMethod. You payout to an [External Account](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/payouts-bank-accounts).